# Different kind of redirection in a portlet

Tags: liferay, portlet

I would like to know the different kind of redirections in the portets and how to realize them. How to go from one view (jsp file) to another in the same portlet, how to go from one page to another from a portlet. It is for the purpose of making a form so I would like to do this in a processAction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is not clear. 
However, in Liferay, you can route your application using urls. 
For example, you can create a portlet action url on your own. 
You can try something like this:

```
HttpServletRequest request = PortalUtil.getOriginalServletRequest(PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(actionRequest));
PortletURL oPortletURL = PortletURLFactoryUtil.create(request, <portletName> , <plid>, <portletPhase>);
oPortletURL.setParameter("myParameter1", "parameter1");
String portletURL = oPortletURL.toString();
```

Where:

`<portletName>` is the javax.portlet.name of your portlet 
`<plid>` is the ID of a page where is located an instance of your `<portletName>` portlet (try to check Layout and LayoutFriendlyUrl tables) 
`<portletPhase>` is the phase you need, for example `PortletRequest.ACTION_PHASE`

Finally, you can use `setParameter()` method to pass parameters in query string.

Comment: How can I put an object in "oPortletURL" instead of a string. If it possible, will `actionResponse.sendRedirect(portletURL);` still allow me to perform the redirection?

Comment: No, you can't pass a parameter which is not a string because the ```portletURL``` String is just an url. You can try using ```request.setAttribute(<aKey>, <anObject>)```. Let me know if it works.

Comment: How to send `request` to the next page in this case?

Answer (score 1):

On the jsp for a single portlet: If you use Liferay's `MVCPortlet`, you can just add the `mvcPath` parameter with the name of the JSP, to make sure your portlet renders with this JSP. Nothing else.

Pages have a URL. If you want to redirect to another page, you'll have to configure the page's URL somewhere. However, that's rarely done unless you're implementing a Navigation portlet. Your question sounds more like you have a multi-page portlet.

Comment: Please can I have more information on redirecting to another page?